# Nested Reference Field

Tags: react-admin

In order to retrieve the equipment type I am using a that will retrieve the equipment model and then another that references the equipment type using the equipment model's field "typeID" to retrieve the equipment type.

However it displays the following warning:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop translateChoice of type
>   boolean supplied to ReferenceField, expected function.

The image represents the data model (an equipment has an equipment model, and an equipment model has an equipment type)

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Support for resource nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255057/support-for-resource-nesting)

Answer (score 8):

I found a better solution is kinda of an hack but seems to be more efficient.

Taking the question example **where in order to get equipmentType is only needed `<ReferenceField>`**, it would be something like this:

```js
    const EquipList = ({...props}) => {
      <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>

          <ReferenceFieldController label="Equipment Type" reference="equipmentModel" source="modelID" linkType={false}>
            {({referenceRecord, ...props}) => (
              <ReferenceField basePath="/equipmentModel" resource="equipmentModel" reference="equipmentType" source="typeID" record={referenceRecord || {}} linkType="show">
                <TextField source="name" />
              </ReferenceField>
            )}
          </RefenceFieldController>

        </Datagrid>
      </List>
    }
```

In the example above `<ReferenceFieldController>` fetches the equipmentModel of equipment, as like `<ReferenceField>`. Label is needed because RA uses the first `<ReferenceField>` to show the column header in `<Datagrid>`, if you use internationalization you should apply translate function to the correct resource on this prop.

`<ReferenceController>` fetches the record and passes it as `referenceRecord` to a child function that will render the component for field presentation. Instead of presenting the field component you render a `<ReferenceField>` to fetch the nested relation and next you show the field. Since `<ReferenceFieldController>` only passes controller props to its child and the props of field component don't do what you want in the nested relation, you have to explicit pass them to `<ReferenceField>`. You need to pass `record` of `<ReferenceField>` as `referenceRecord || {}` because the initially the `referenceRecord` is not fetched yet and `<ReferenceField>` doesn't work with record as null.

Setting the `linkType` of `<ReferenceFieldController`> to false makes it not render a `<Link>` component that would redirect the user to an incorrect route.

Answer (score 4):

Not a perfect fix, but to get around the `translateChoice` issue, you can create a wrapper and pluck out that prop to prevent it from being passed.

```js
const SubReference = ({ translateChoice, children, ...props }) => (
    <ReferenceField {...props}>{children}</ReferenceField>
);
```

While troubleshooting this, I was also receiving an error about nested `a` tags. I was able to silence the error by setting the `linkType` prop to `false` in the parent `ReferenceField`

```js
<ReferenceField source="item_id" reference="list" linkType={false}>
    <SubReference source="id_to_reference_from_list" reference="second_list">
        <TextField source="name" />
    </SubReference>
</ReferenceField>
```

Comment: this works in terms of showing the correct reference. However, the <SubReference> does not seem to link to the correct resource.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I think this is an actual bug. I commented on the corresponding github issue https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/2140

I looked into the code for `ReferenceField` and as far as I understood this is an actual bug. `ReferenceField` expects a function for the `translateChoice` property, but internally hands a boolean to `ReferenceFieldView`.
If you nest one `ReferenceField` into another the inner one receives `false` as `translateChoice` property and rightfully complains that it is a boolean and not a function.