# Best way to support resource nesting in react-admin

Tags: reactjs, nested, react-admin

I'm building a react-admin app communicates with server via the `ra-data-simple-rest` dataProvider.

I saw here [Support for resource nesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54255057/support-for-resource-nesting) that react-admin doesnt support in resource nesting,
but it was a long time ago so I wonder if something was changed?

If not how sholud I enable support in resource nesting like: `Get /resurce1/:id/resurce2`?

I have very little knowledge in React and React admin so if you could to clarify me how to do it in the best way short and work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It hasn't changed. If your API forces you to use this kind of routes then it's your dataProvider job to handle it.

Comment: thank's I try to implement a suitable dataProvider but I have little knowledge of ts and react. Could you refer me to a good example. to understand how to implement it.