# React Admin - Merging/combining 2 referenceFields

Tags: react-admin

What I want to achieve is to combine data from 3 tables into one column where the middle table is my resource.

| door-model | sensor | sensor-report |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id | id | id |
|  | idModel | idSensor |

so far I have managed to get the sensor and report data but I'm struggling to get the record for the model.

```js
const CustomField: React.FC<
  FieldProps<DoorModel> & Partial<{ sensor: Sensor }>
> = (props) => {
  return <>hello</>;
};

const CRMFReport: React.FC<ReferenceManyFieldProps> = ({
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  return <ReferenceManyField {...props}>{children}</ReferenceManyField>;
};

const CRFModel: React.FC<FieldProps<Sensor>> = ({
  record,
  resource,
  basePath,
}) => {
  return (
    <ReferenceFieldController
      resource={resource ?? ''}
      basePath={basePath ?? ''}
      reference="door-model"
      source="idModel"
    >
      {({ referenceRecord, ...rest }) => (
        <CRMFReport
          reference="sensor-report"
          target="idSensor"
          sort={{ field: 'time', order: 'DESC' }}
          perPage={1}
          page={1}
        >
          <ArrayField>
            <SingleFieldList>
              <CustomField sensor={record} props={referenceRecord} />
            </SingleFieldList>
          </ArrayField>
        </CRMFSensorReport>
      )}
    </ReferenceFieldController>
  );
};

const SensorList = (props: ListProps): React.ReactElement => {
  return (
    <List {...props} actions={<AdminListActions />}>
      <Datagrid rowClick="show">
        <CRFModel />
      </Datagrid>
    </List>
  );
};
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53435034/11437986) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53161132/11437986) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: There is absolutely no difference between the report and the model record structure. Please, provide more info on what is stopping you from retrieving the model record. Also you have either misleading names of the fields in the table or in the code. If you make them equal it will be easier to spot a mistake.

Comment: @KiaKaha there is no need to show any more data. This table shows that there are 3 tables and 2 of them are related to the middle table. what they contain, doesn't matter in this question. I will edit the discrepancy.